# How do I get timestamps to generate in Azure speech to text model?

Tags: c#, azure, speech-to-text

I'm trying to generate and collect data using Azure's speech to text code. I want to generate timestamps, reduce redundancies in the output, and export to Excel. The code below runs with no errors:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace NEST
{
internal class NewBaseType
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)

    {
        // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and region.
        // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("subscriptionkey", "region");

        // Generates timestamps
        config.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed;
        config.RequestWordLevelTimestamps();

        //calls the audio file
        using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("C:/Users/MichaelSchwartz/source/repos/AI-102-Process-Speech-master/transcribe_speech_to_text/media/narration.wav"))

        // Creates a speech recognizer from microphone.
        using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput))
        {
            // Subscribes to events.
            recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: Text={e.Result.Text}");
            };

            recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
            {
                var result = e.Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"Reason: {result.Reason.ToString()}");
                if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Final result: Text: {result.Text}.");
                }
            };

            recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\n    Canceled. Reason: {e.Reason.ToString()}, CanceledReason: {e.Reason}");
            };

            recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n    Session started event.");
            };

            recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
            };

            recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) => 
            { 
                var j = e.Result.Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult);
            };

            // Starts continuous recognition. 
            // Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
            await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to stop");
            } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

            // Stops recognition.
            await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I run it, I don't see timestamp data. How do I generate timestamp data?

Also, is there a way to remove redundancies in the output? Example:

```
RECOGNIZING: Text=the
RECOGNIZING: Text=the speech
RECOGNIZING: Text=the speech translation
RECOGNIZING: Text=the speech translation API
RECOGNIZING: Text=the speech translation API transcribes
RECOGNIZING: Text=the speech translation API transcribes audio
```

I just want the final result. Is there a way to remove the "RECOGNIZING:" data from the output while preserving accuracy? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing the `"RECOGNIZING:"`, just delete this sentence:

```
recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: Text={e.Result.Text}");
};
```

I didn't see where you export the result and timestamps to Excel. You could use this code after you got the `SpeechRecognitionResult` object:

```
var json = result.Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The output of that is：
[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solutions for exporting the results to Excel automatically. My current solution is to copy/paste from the terminal to Excel. Does a solution for auto exporting to Excel exist?

Comment: I have the following code in lines 52-55 but no timestamps are generated:

            recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) => 
            { 
                var j = e.Result.Properties.GetProperty(PropertyId.SpeechServiceResponse_JsonResult);
            };

How do I call/print "j" such that the timestamps are generated and formatted correctly?